# Form resolution suddenly changes after datagridview update

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, resolution

I have this problem: my form module changes resolution unexpectedly during runtime.

I have a form module which contains a DataGridView and when I run the form everything is fine, the form is displayed correctly.
However, when I drag & drop on the form, it suddenly changes resolution without my being able to find an explanation.

[image: Form before drag & drop]
[image: Form after drag & drop]

The application target framework is .NET 4.5.2

I have verified that the problem occurs when calling the Update and Refresh methods on the DataGridView component, but despite having made countless attempts I do not understand what the problem is.

```
        this.dataGridView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.dataGridView.Update()));
        this.dataGridView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.dataGridView.Refresh()));
```

Here are the seetings of the Form and of the DataGridView component

[image: Form layout settings]
[image: DataGridView layout settings]

Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: I would check if you have any autosize setting on the window. It might try to fit the window size to the content.

Comment: thanks @R.Czq
AutoSize of the form is false, AutoScaleMode is Font

Comment: What are your device's DPI / Font Scaling options? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-text-and-apps-bigger-c3095a80-6edd-4779-9282-623c4d721d64

Comment: @MarcelPiquet I would then try to set the AutoScaleMode to none and see if that has any impact. You can also try to play with the AutoSizeColumnsMode of the dataGridView and set that to none as well. If either of these 2 things helps you can then try to isolate which one is causing the issue. You could also try to do a mock project with similar code to see if this happens with a simplified version of your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the issue was not in the layout/properties of the form nor in the dataGridView component settings, but it was triggered by a third party library: GemBox.Pdf which somehow was sensible to the DPI of the screen.

Putting `[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]` into the file AssemblyInfo.cs solved the issue

Many Thanks everyone for the help!!